# valgrind Invalid write of size 8 in a allocated memory

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

I am trying to add new node to my linked list, but it's gives memory error

my struct and global vars:

```
typedef struct word word;

struct word
{
    char str[256];
    word *next;
};

word *head = NULL;
word *cur = NULL;
```

the function :

```
int addWord(char * str)
{
    word *w = calloc(1, sizeof(w));

    if(w == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }  
    strcpy(w->str, str);

    if(cur == NULL)
    {
        cur = w;
        head = w;
    }
    else
    {
puts("4");
        cur->next = w;
puts("5");
        cur = w;
puts("6");    
    }
    return 1;
}
```

and the result is :

```
...
4
5
6
4
==73913== Invalid write of size 8
==73913==    at 0x109425: addWord (in /home/mz37/programming/godaphy/bin/godaphy.out)
==73913==    by 0x109696: parseLine (in /home/mz37/programming/godaphy/bin/godaphy.out)
==73913==    by 0x109351: main (in /home/mz37/programming/godaphy/bin/godaphy.out)
==73913==  Address 0x4a6a880 is 96 bytes inside an unallocated block of size 4,188,096 in arena "client"
==73913== 
5
6
```

i am still searching for the error and i haven't found it yet

Comment: Just another boring typo: `sizeof(w);` -> `sizeof(*w)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
word *w = calloc(1, sizeof(w));
```

The `w` variable is of type `word` *pointer* hence is likely to be four or eight bytes at most. It *may* be larger if we end up with 128-bit machines at some point, but it'll be quite some time before it gets to 2000+ bits :-)

You probably wanted to do:

```
word *w = calloc(1, sizeof(*w));
//            note this ___^
```

The type of `*w` is the actual type `word`, and that *will* be the correct size for what you're trying to do.

---

And, as an aside, you may want to think about the wisdom of blindly copying whatever string you're given, into a block of memory that can only hold 256 characters. A safer alternative would be:

```
strncpy(w->str, str, sizeof(w->str) - 1);
// Would normally also do something like:
//     w->str[sizeof(w->str) - 1] = '\0';
// but calloc() makes that superfluous.
```

---

The resultant function (including compactifying) would be along the following lines:

```
int addWord(char *str) {
    word *w;

    // Option to fail if string too big, rather than truncate.

    //if (strlen(str) >= sizeof(w->str)
    //    return 0;

    // Allocate and check.

    if ((w = calloc(1, sizeof(*w)))  == NULL)
        return 0;

    // Copy in string, truncate if too big.

    strncpy(w->str, str, sizeof(w->str) - 1);

    // Make new list if currently empty, otherwise add it, then flag success.

    if(cur == NULL) {
        cur = head = w;
    } else {
        cur->next = w;
        cur = w;
    }

    return 1;
}
```